# Confusion about string find?

Tags: python

I have a list of data that I want to search through. This new list of data is structured like so.

name, address dob family members age height etc..

I want to search through the lines of data so that I stop the search at the ',' that appears after the name to optimize the search. I believe I want to use this command:

```
str.find(sub[, start[, end]])
```

I'm having trouble writing the code in this structure though. Any tips on how to make string find work for me?

Here is some sample data:

```
Bennet, John, 17054099","5","156323558","-","0", 714 // 
Menendez, Juan,7730126","5","158662525" 11844 // 
Brown,  Jamal,"9","22966592","+","0",,"4432 //
```

The idea is I want my program to search only to the first ',' and not search through the rest of the large lines.

EDIT. So here is my code.

I want the to search the lines in completedataset only until the first comma. I'm still confused as to how I should implement these suggestions into my existing code.

```
counter = 1
 for line in completedataset:
     print counter
     counter +=1
     for t in matchedLines:
         if t in line:
             smallerdataset.write(line)
```

Comment: Can you give an example of your list of data?

Comment: What are those `//`? New lines?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand your specs correctly,

```
for thestring in listdata:
    firstcomma = thestring.find(',')
    havename = thestring.find(name, 0, firstcomma)
    if havename >= 0:
        print "found name:", thestring[:firstcomma]
```

**Edit**: given the OP's edit of the Q, this would become something like:

```
 counter = 1
 for line in completedataset:
     print counter
     counter += 1
     firstcomma = thestring.find(',')
     havename = thestring.find(t, 0, firstcomma)
     if havename >= 0:
         smallerdataset.write(line)
```

Of course, the use of `counter` is unPythonically low-level, and a better eqv would be

```
 for counter, line in enumerate(completedataset):
     print counter + 1
     firstcomma = thestring.find(',')
     havename = thestring.find(t, 0, firstcomma)
     if havename >= 0:
         smallerdataset.write(line)
```

but that doesn't affect the question as asked.

Comment: So how can I integrate this into the code I already have...see my edited post. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

You can do it quite directly:

```
s = 'Bennet, John, 17054099","5","156323558","-","0", 714 //'
print s.find('John', 0, s.index(',')) # find the index of ',' and stop there
```

Answer (score 0):

You will probably search in each line, so you can just split them by ', ' and then do a search on a first element:

```
for line in file:
   name=line.split(', ')[0]
   if name.find('smth'):
       break
```

Comment: why smth? I have multiple lines and multiple names that I want to search through.

Answer (score 0):

Any reason why you have to use find?
Why not just do something like:

```
if str.split(",", 1)[0] == search_string:
    ...
```

**Edit:**
Just thought I'd point out - I was just testing this and the `split` approach seems just as fast (if not faster than find). Test the performance of both approaches using the `timeit` module and see what you get.

Try:

```
python -m timeit -n 10000 -s "a='''Bennet, John, 17054099','5','156323558','-','0', 714'''" "a.split(',',1)[0] == 'Bennet'"
```

then compare with:

```
python -m timeit -n 10000 -s "a='''Bennet, John, 17054099','5','156323558','-','0', 714'''" "a.find('Bennet', 0, a.find(','))"
```

Make the name longer (e.g `"BennetBennetBennetBennetBennetBennet"`) and you realize that find suffers more than split

**Note:** am using `split` with the `maxsplit` option

Comment: The OP said he didn't want to process the long lines; using split will examine the entire line and build the array of all fields when he clearly wants optimize by NOT processing the whole line.

Comment: Yeah this is exactly what I do NOT want to do.

Answer (score 0):

If you're checking a lot of names against each line, it seems like the biggest optimization might be only processing each line for commas once!

```
for line in completedataset:
    i = line.index(',')
    first_field = line[:i]
    for name in matchedNames:
        if name in first_field:
            smalldataset.append(name)
```